# Count number of zeros after last non-zero value per row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following df:

| index | jan | feb | marc | april |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| two | 0 | 8 | 7 | 0 |
| three | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I'd like to get the number of zeros after the last non-zero value per row. So the output should look like

| index | num |
| --- | --- |
| One | 2 |
| two | 1 |
| three | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar logic to that of @BrJ but more straightforward in my opinion.

Using a reversed [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html) to set to `False` all `True` preceding a `False`, then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
out = (df.loc[:,::-1].eq(0)
         .cummin(axis=1).sum(axis=1)
         .to_frame('num')
       )
```

Output:

```
       num
One      2
two      1
three    0
```

Intermediates:

```
# boolean mask (0s are True)
         jan    feb   marc  april
One    False  False   True   True
two     True  False  False   True
three   True   True   True  False

# after reversed cummin (and reversed again for clarity)
# all True that preceded a False are now False
         jan    feb   marc  april
One    False  False   True   True
two    False  False  False   True
three  False  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe
data = {
    'jan': [1, 0, 0],
    'feb': [7, 8, 0],
    'marc': [0, 7, 0],
    'april': [0, 0, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['One', 'two', 'three'])

# Calculate the number of zeros after the last non-zero value per index/row
num_zeros = df.ne(0).iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1)

# Result dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame({'num': num_zeros}, index=df.index)

print("DataFrame:")
print(df)
print("\nResult:")
print(result)
```

Calculating the # of zeroes (*df.ne(0).iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1)*):

- ne method to check inequality with zero (df.ne(0))
- perform cumulative sum along the columns in reverse order (iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)) to get a binary representation of
  non-zero values after the last non-zero value
- check where the cumulative product equals zero (eq(0)) and sum along the rows (sum(axis=1)) to get the count

Prints:

```
DataFrame:
       jan  feb  marc  april
One      1    7     0      0
two      0    8     7      0
three    0    0     0      1

Result:
       num
One      2
two      1
three    0
```